# continuous averaging using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl, moving-average

I have a question related to VHDL programming. I want to calculate the continuous average. My example code is:

```
process (clk, reset)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then 
        state<=idle;
        out-val=0;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case state is

            when idle =>
                if req='1' then 
                    state= out-1;
                end if;

            when out-1 =>
                if done='1' then
                    out-val<=data-in (11 downto 0);
                    state <= done-st;
                endif;

            when done-st =>
                ack <='1';
                state <= idle;

            when others =>
                state <= idle;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

On every positive edge of clock, the value of "out-val" changes. I want to continuously take the average of "out-val". I want to take average of 32 values continuously. Is there a way where I can take average of 32 values continuously till the clock is running. Kindly let me know how can I do that. You can modify the above code as well.

Many Thanks,

Comment: You should use underscores instead of dashes.  It looks like you are doing math in your state machine.  "when out-1" is confusing.

Comment: O yeah. Actually I used underscore in my original code. I don't know why did I write '-1' here. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a running total of the 32 values.  You can keep a running total by having a signal that has the total count.  On each clock cycle, you need to add-in the newest value and subtract-out the oldest value.  This means that you need to create a large shift-register or FIFO to keep track of the previous 32 values so you can remove them in order.

Then to get the average just do a shift-right to divide by 32.

Comment: Do I have to create a separate process for doing this?

Comment: I would recommend it.  Keep your state machine logic separate from your running average.

Comment: @user3008991 what answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create 32 tap FIR filter whose coeffients are 1/32[1, 1,..... 1]

Comment: Yes, I did. So?